# Why using raw type causes the properties to become raw?

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic class, defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseModel<T extends BaseModel> extends BaseEntity<T> {
    ...
    public Map<String,List<BaseModelConcrete>> itemsToDelete = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

every time I get a `BaseModel` argument to a function, the property becomes `Map`, but when I change the argument to `BaseModel<?>` the argument is `Map<String,List<BaseModelConcrete>>` again.

Why is that ?

Comment: @sotirios delimanolis I saw this question. But I still can't figure this out, since the class' gentrification, isn't related to properties.

Comment: Everything is erased.